# Selecting format for addresses returned from ggmap's revgeocode

Tags: r, google-maps, google-api, ggmap, google-geocoding-api

When you grab the address for a geolocation in R it defaults to the first entry. How can I return one of the others instead?

> revgeocode(c(-122.39150, 37.77374), output = "address")
>   
>   Multiple addresses found, the first will be returned:
>     1145 4th St, San Francisco, CA 94158, USA
>     ...
>     San Francisco County, CA, USA
>     San Francisco, CA, USA
>     California, USA
>     United States

Answer (score 0):

You can use `output="all"` and then access the `$results` array to get the specific entry you want.

E.g.:

```
revgeocode(c(-122.39150, 37.77374), output = "all")$results[[6]]$formatted_address
```

This returns the 6th address, "San Francisco, CA 94158, USA".

Hope this helps!